# What are the rim size options for fat bikes?

Tags: fatbike

I recently purchased a fat bike through the internet, and found to my surprise, that it had 3" tires, and not 4" tires.

What are the common fat bike rim sizes, and tire sizes?  I'm primarily interested in width, as I am looking for a commuting bike to ride through a lot of snowy crud, and am looking for wheel/tire options to replace on this newly purchased bike.

Comment: Generally, everyone was doing clones of whatever Surly/Salsa had been selling. Fat bikes are still a niche item with only a few manufacturers making parts, with budget makers like BikesDirect starting to get a flurry of fat bikes out now, it becomes more complicated. You also need to consider the hub spacing in the front as well (and find someone who is selling/building these wheels up, since I imagine they'd be more complicated than normal wheels).

Comment: @Batman  I might have agreed with that statement 2 years ago.  However, Specialized is now making tires for fatbikes.  It's seriously blown up.  When I started Surly made tires and that was it (tires are always the sticking point for new wheel sizes).  Now I believe that are probably at least six companies selling different tire options.

Comment: There are currently very few 26" x 3.0" tires on the market, and to my knowledge, none of them come as original equipment on complete bikes.

Are you sure your tires aren't 26" x 3.7" or 3.8"?

Comment: Ah, @MichaelLemberger, my mistake was that I bought a bike that I thought was a fat bike, but was a 29er.  So, it has 29" diameter wheels, with 3" wide tires.  I've learned a ton since my post.  So much so, that I may even post an answer....